# Google Cloud SQL or node-mysql answers a long time

Tags: google-cloud-sql, node-mysql

We have this project using Polymer as the FrontEnd and Node.js as the API being consumed by Polymer, and our Node API replies a really long time especially if you just leave the page alone for like 10 minutes. Upon further investigation by inserting a DATE calculation in the MySQL Query, I found out that MySQL responds a Really long time. The query looks like this:

```
var query = dataStruct['formed_query'];
console.log(query);
var now = Date.now();
console.log("Getting Data for Foobar Query============ "+Date());
console.log(query);
GLOBAL.db_foobar.getConnection(function(err1, connection) {
    ////console.log("requesting MySQL connection");
    if(err1==null)
    {
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows,fields){
            console.log("response from MySQL Foobar Query============= "+Date());
            console.log("MySQL response Foobar Query=========> "+(Date.now()-now)+" ms");
            if(err==null)
            {
                //respond.respondJSON is just a res.json(msg); but I've added a similar calculation for response time starting from express router.route until res.json occurs
                respond.respondJSON(dataJSON['resVal'],res,req);

            }else{
                var msg = {
                    "status":"Error",
                    "desc":"[Foobar Query]Error Getting Connection",
                    "err":err1,
                    "db_name":"common",
                    "query":query
                };
                respond.respondError(msg,res,req);
            }
            connection.release();
        });
    }else{
        var msg = {
            "status":"Error",
            "desc":"[Foobar Query]Error Getting Connection",
            "err":err1,
            "db_name":"common",
            "query":query
        };
        respond.respondJSON(msg,res,req);
        respond.emailError(msg);
        try{
            connection.release();
        }catch(err_release){
            respond.LogInConsole(err_release);
            respond.LogInConsole(err_release.stack);
        }
    }
});
```

}

When Chrome Developer tools reports a LONG PENDING time for the API, this happens to my log.

```
SELECT * FROM `foobar_table`  LIMIT 0,20;
MySQL response Foobar Query=========> 10006 ms
```

I'm dumbfounded as to why this is happening.

We have our system hosted in Google Cloud Services. Our MySQL is a Google SQL service with an activation policy of ALWAYS. We've also set that our Node Server, which is a Google Compute Engine, to keep alive TCP4 connections via:

```
echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo /sbin/sysctl --load=/etc/sysctl.conf
```

I'm using mysql Pool from node-mysql

```
db_init.database = 'foobar_dbname';
db_init=ssl_set(db_init);
//GLOBAL.db_foobar = mysql.createConnection(db_init);
GLOBAL.db_foobar = mysql.createPool(db_init);
GLOBAL.db_foobar.on('connection', function (connection) {
    setTimeout(tryForceRelease, mysqlForceTimeOut,connection);
});
```

db_init looks like this:

```
db_init = {
            host     : 'ip_address_of_GCS_SQL',
            user     : 'user_name_of_GCS_SQL[![enter image description here][1]][1]',
            password : '',
            database : '',
            supportBigNumbers: true,
            connectionLimit:100
        };
```

I'm also forcing to release connections if they're not released in 2 minutes, just to make sure it's released

```
function tryForceRelease(connection)
{
    try{
        //console.log("force releasing connection");
        connection.release();
    }catch(err){
        //do nothing
        //console.log("connection already released");
    }
}
```

This is really wracking my brains out here. If anyone can help please do.
[image: LONG PENDING IMAGE]

Comment: Just on a side note, when this doesn't happen, the response time for MySQL is 3-7ms and my Total Response time is between 61ms to (at worst) 500ms

Comment: try enabling the slow query log (https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues#query-logs) in MySQL to narrow down/confirm the location of the slowness. Also what kind of machine type are you using for the GCE instance and what tier is the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Thanks for the response, we've turned on the slow query logs. We're using D4 tier for the GCS-SQL (4GB memory) and we're using the 1CPU, 3.75GB Compute Engine (lowest default setup) with 40GB SSD for the NODE server

Comment: Update: I have had this instance also when Chome Dev Tools say it's delayed 2 minutes BUT my API says it responded in 21ms

Comment: Update2: Have not yet found a MySQL delay that corresponds to the delay that Chrome Dev Tools reported. But the delay is still reported by Chrome

Comment: Update3: I just realized for the slow log to work I have to remove the force connection.release routine. Waiting for data gathering again

Comment: Still no slow queries from MySQL Logs

Comment: Would you be willing to try node-mysql2 (https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) to rule out node-mysql as the cause of issues?

Comment: way ahead of you Vadim, used it and, although the instances of the delays are farther, but they still occur. And I just left it to run in the server for the past 2 days without touching it, the connections now emit an error ETIMEDOUT. I think the mysql pool system in node's mysql module (or mysql2) has a problem or maybe I should be checking for connection timeouts/disconnects? I checked MySQL via SHOW PROCESSLIST; and the original 25 connections that I had became 5 with a sleep status. And these errors occur already. Maybe I should veer away from using the MySQL pool for the moment

Comment: 25 connections from the server since there are 5 Node APIs with, if I'm not mistaken, 5 minimum connections for each pool.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas :) One thing you can try is lowering mysql's wait_timeout to a really low value (say 15 minutes) and see what effect it has. If it exacerbates the issue, then we know the issue is due to idle connections, if it doesn't have any effect then we don't know anything yet :) (I wouldn't recommend performing this experiment on a production system, from looking at the node-mysql[2] code they don't seem to handle idle connections very well)

Answer (score 1):

I'll post the same answer here as I posted in [node-mysql pool experiences ETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546586/node-mysql-pool-experiences-etimedout).
The questions are sufficiently different that I'm not sure it's worth duping them.

---

I suspect the reason is that keepalive is not enabled on the connection to the MySQL server.

`node-mysql` does not have an option to enable keepalive and neither does `node-mysql2`, but `node-mysql2` provides a way to supply a custom function for creating sockets which we can use to enable keepalive:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var net = require('net');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 100,
  host            : '123.123.123.123',
  user            : 'foo',
  password        : 'bar',
  database        : 'baz',
  stream          : function(opts) {
    var socket = net.connect(opts.config.port, opts.config.host);
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    return socket;
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow, this is actually good... and it tries to keep the pool alive not just a single connection. Brilliant!