# node-mysql pool experiences ETIMEDOUT

Tags: google-cloud-sql, node-mysql

I have a node-mysql pool configuration of

```
var db_init={
            host     : 'ip_address_of_GCS_SQL',
            user     : 'user_name_of_GCS_SQL',
            password : 'password here',
            database : 'db here',
            supportBigNumbers: true,
            connectionLimit:100
};
```

Pool was created using

```
GLOBAL.db_foobar = mysql.createPool(db_init);
```

I basically just left the connection on for a couple of hours and I saw this error reported by my connection.query Request (after getConnection of course):

```
prodAPI-104 (out): { status: 'Error',
prodAPI-104 (out):   details: '[foobar_function]Error in query',
prodAPI-104 (out):   err: '{ [Error: read ETIMEDOUT]\n  code: \'ETIMEDOUT\',\n      errno: \'ETIMEDOUT\',\n  syscall: \'read\',\n  fatal: true }',
prodAPI-104 (out):   query: 'SELECT * FROM `foobar_table`;' }
```

Why is this happening? The MySQL in Google-Cloud-SQL didn't report a query taking too long to create so I dunno why this happened.

Comment: How long after fresh application startup does this happen? I looked at the node-mysql code and it looks like it doesn't clean up idle connections, which doesn't match mysql behavior (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout)

Comment: I was a bit off: while it doesn't remove idle connections, node-mysql does check that the connection is up before it returns it to you so that shouldn't be a problem. How much data is in this table? If it's truly a lot of data and it's not in memory, the query could be slow.

Comment: Barely 20 rows of data &  not even 10 columns. No texts, just Big INTs & some varchar 255.

Comment: That's really odd, approximately how many hours after application startup do you start seeing this message?

Comment: From what I can recall, just leaving it overnight (8 hours) will result in this error

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that keepalive is not enabled on the connection to the MySQL server.

`node-mysql` does not have an option to enable keepalive and neither does `node-mysql2`, but `node-mysql2` provides a way to supply a custom function for creating sockets which we can use to enable keepalive:

```js
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var net = require('net');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit : 100,
  host            : '123.123.123.123',
  user            : 'foo',
  password        : 'bar',
  database        : 'baz',
  stream          : function(opts) {
    var socket = net.connect(opts.config.port, opts.config.host);
    socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    return socket;
  }
});
```