# Cannot set tcp_keepalive_time on google cloud compute engine instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, keep-alive, gcloud

we are running a node.js server that needs to connect with a mySQL database. We hosted our database on amazon RDS, but now we've moved it over to Google SQL and we're having trouble with the server randomly dropping the connection after 10 minutes.

Apparently that's a feature, not a bug, and the workaround is setting a low tcp keepalive in the machine we're connecting from, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/diagnose-issues

The code should be:

```
echo 'net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 60' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
sudo /sbin/sysctl --load=/etc/sysctl.conf
```

Unfortunately, when running the code I get:

```
sysctl: cannot stat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time: No such file or directory
```

We have root access to this machine, but we can't even manually creating a file named tcp_keepalive_time in this folder.

We're extremely puzzled, as the solution comes from the official google Cloud SQL docs and should therefore work as described.

Has anyone got any insights to share? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this a first generation or second generation instance?

Comment: It's also due to node-mysql/node-mysql2 drivers not enabling keepalive (unlike most other MySQL drivers). Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35710201/350488

Answer (score 1):

Auto-answer:

You can't access the filesystem as admin (apparently) **from the web/cloud console.**

We used gcloud auth (from the gcloud SDK) to log in from the therminal, puttygen to create a SSH key and then putty to SSH into the machine from a **proper ssh client** (instead of the cloud SSH console), and sure enough it worked.

Weird, hope this helps someone else with the same issue!